# I want to make row as column using pivot in SQL Server 2008 but columns have string values so can not apply aggregate function to it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I need to convert rows to column, but there is no numeric values as pivot function requires aggregate function to be apply while converting to columns from rows

This is my table in SQL Server:

[image]

Data needs to be retrieved like this:

[image]

I tried this query but it shows error

```
SELECT 
    title, price
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         Product_Attributes_String_Value, Attribute_ID_Name, Product_ID 
     FROM
         [Products].[dbo].[Product_Attributes] 
     WHERE 
         Product_ID = '20734381') AS Tab1
PIVOT  
    (Product_Attributes_String_Value 
         FOR Attribute_ID_Name IN (title, price)) AS Tab2 
ORDER BY 
    [Tab2].[price]
```

Comment: You can wrap text value with aggregate function. Try: `MAX(Product_Attributes_String_Value)`

Comment: You can apply MAX aggregate function on String.

Comment: And you can also apply `MIN` and `COUNT` to string column - no problem

Comment: I applied Max function for Product_Attributes_String_Value column but getting price column value as null, will anyone suggest me select query as i shown table and expected result

Answer (score 0):

No need for PIVOT

```
SELECT a.Product_ID, 
    a.Product_Attributes_String_Value as title, 
    b.Product_Attributes_Double_Value as price
FROM [Products].[dbo].[Product_Attributes] a
    LEFT JOIN [Products].[dbo].[Product_Attributes] b 
        ON a.Product_ID = b.Product_ID 
        AND b.Attribute_ID_Name = ‘price’
WHERE a.Product_ID = ‘20734381’ 
    AND a.Attribute_ID_Name = ‘title’
```